# Having trouble getting Camel to use JDNI for database connection

Tags: jndi

I am having trouble getting Camel to work with jndi. I am deploying camel inside of IBM Websphere.
Inside of Websphere there is a jdni connection called "vzw.ds.commerce" that is setup to connect to the database I want to access.
This route below works:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="publishDB">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server.com:2051/mbschema" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="commerceDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="vzw.ds.commerce" />
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="timer-to-console" customId="true">
        <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10s" />
        <transform>
            <simple>30004</simple>
        </transform>
        <process ref="createSQL" />
        <to uri="jdbc:publishDB" />
        <process ref="processSQL" />
        <to uri="stream:out" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

However, I want to use the jndi connection and not have the connection information in the route.
When I change the line to:

I get the error:
java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call DSRA0010E: SQL State = null, Error Code = 17,433

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted actually was correct. The problem I had was with the setup on Websphere.
Once I changed the setting on Websphere the code started working.